# perl help to join records and insert characters

Tags: perl

Perl newbie here...looking for help to reformat a datafile.

Data looks like this:

```
num:3460381591 
num:1038198413 
num:3380733973
```

I would like to make it one string and then append each start of the rec with `^a` and `^b` after the colon like this:

```
^anum:^b3460381591^anum:^b1038198413^anum:^b3380733973
```

Can someone show me how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $str = '';

open FILE, "file";
while (<FILE>) {
    chomp;
    my ($k, $v) = split /:/;
    $str .= "^a$k:^b$v";
}
close FILE;

print "$str\n";
```

Comment: can you tell me what the `.=` is doing?

Comment: "$a .= $b" is shortcut notation for "$a = $a . $b" -- i.e., append $b to the end of whatever is already in $a.

Answer (score 3):

If Perl is not a must,

```
$ awk -F":" '{$1="^a"$1;$2="^b"$2}1' OFS=":" ORS="" file
^anum:^b3460381591^anum:^b1038198413^anum:^b3380733973
```

else,

```
perl -F":" -ane 'chomp($F[1]);$F[0]="^a$F[0]";$F[1]="^b$F[1]"; print join ":", @F ' file
```

Or how about this?

```
perl -ne 'chomp; s/^/^a/;s/:/:^b/;print' file
```

Comment: Here's one more way: `perl -ne'chomp; s/^([^:]+:)/^a$1^b/; print }{ print "\n"' file`

Answer (score 2):

An easy way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p

s/^(\w+):(.*?)\s*$/^a$1:^b$2/;
```

Or if you want to edit a file in place (and backup the original file in place):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -pi.BAK

s/^(\w+):(.*?)\s*$/^a$1:^b$2/;
```

You can, of course, also run these as one-liners:

```
perl -p -e 's/^(\w+):(.*?)\s*$/^a$1:^b$2/;' filename
perl -pi.BAK -e 's/^(\w+):(.*?)\s*$/^a$1:^b$2/;' filename
```

See [perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for details.